# Что за ошибка в npm debug(angular 2)?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Только начал изучать angular 2 делал всё как в уроке, это моё первое hello world приложение, вся структура проекта писалась с нуля, в конце делаю npm start и выдаёт сие ошибку, как исправить?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.5.2
3 info using node@v4.7.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/share/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/user/Рабочий стол/Temp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
10 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/user/Рабочий стол/Temp
11 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" ' ]
12 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
13 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
14 verbose stack Exit status 2
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:232:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:854:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
15 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/user/Рабочий стол/Temp
17 error Linux 4.10.0-33-generic
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v4.7.2
20 error npm  v3.5.2
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" `
22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite" '.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     tsc && concurrently "npm run tsc:w" "npm run lite"
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: `Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed` не проверял?

Comment: Нашёл 2 решения ошибок. 
1) "skipLibCheck": true добавляем в tsconfig.json
2) Изменяем сервер/порты для lite-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл 2 решения ошибок.

> 1) "skipLibCheck": true добавляем в tsconfig.json 2) Изменяем
>   сервер/порты для lite-server